# how to import workbox defaultRouter

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

there is the example [Workbox Routing/Advanced Usage](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#advanced_usage)

But when I tried it I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: DefaultRouter is not defined

there my service-worker:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.2.0/workbox-sw.js");

workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true
});

const router = new DefaultRouter();
router.registerRoute(new RegExpRoute( /\/index\.html/, workbox.strategies.networkFirst()));
router.registerRoute(new RegExpRoute( /main\.min\.js/, workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate()));
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const responsePromise = router.handleRequest(event);
  if (responsePromise) {
    // Router found a route to handle the request
    event.respondWith(responsePromise);
  } else {
    // No route found to handle the request
    console.debug('workbox has no route to handle request ', event.request);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled upon the same issue.

It looks like that `DefaultRouter` has been replaced with `Router` https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.routing.Router 
and to initialize you have to do `new workbox.routing.Router()`.

Answer (score 0):

now I find just funny looking bypass:
instead:

```
const router = new DefaultRouter();
```

I use:

```
router = new workbox.routing.constructor();
```